# Python interp2D with complex numbers

Tags: python, scipy

I need to interp2 for python the same way as matlab's interp2 function

I've tried to use scipy interp2d function the same was as matlabs inter2

Matlab: interp2(x,y,yy,new_xx,new_yy)

x = 37, 39, 41

y = 2.5, 2.75, 3

yy = [[0.6 + 1.6j,0.6 + 1.6j,0.6 + 1.6j], [0.7 + 1.6j, 0.7 + 1.6j, 0.7 + 1.6j], [0.8 + 1.5j, 0.8 + 1.5j, 0.8 + 1.5j]] - 3x3 array

new_xx = np.linspace(37,41,401)

new_yy = np.linspace(0,3,401)

'''

```
func = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x,y,yy)

arr = func(new_xx,new_yy)
```

'''

I recieve an error when I run func = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x,y,yy)
"ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part"

How can I interperolate with complex numbers?

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to perform two different interpolations: "If V contains complex numbers, then interp2 interpolates the real and imaginary parts separately." from the [interp2 matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html).

Using [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

x = np.array([37, 39, 41])

y = np.array([2.5, 2.75, 3])

z = np.array([[0.6 + 1.6j, 0.6 + 1.6j, 0.6 + 1.6j],
     [0.7 + 1.6j, 0.7 + 1.6j, 0.7 + 1.6j],
     [0.8 + 1.5j, 0.8 + 1.5j, 0.8 + 1.5j]])

# 2D grid interpolation
interpolator_real = interp2d(x, y, np.real(z))
interpolator_imag = interp2d(x, y, np.imag(z))

def interpolator_complex(x, y):
    return interpolator_real(x, y) + 1j*interpolator_imag(x, y)

# test
new_x = np.linspace(37, 41, 6)
new_y = np.linspace(2.5, 3, 8)

interpolator_complex(new_x, new_y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this while converting MATLAB code to Python. It's not exactly intuitive, but the solution that worked for me was actually to use scipy's griddata function as opposed to the interp2d function, as explained here: [How can I perform two-dimensional interpolation using scipy?](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/57896/how-can-i-perform-two-dimensional-interpolation-using-scipy)

Here's the documentation for reference: [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)

OP's would probably look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

points = np.array([x, y]).T
values = yy.ravel() 
xi = np.array([new_xx, new_yy]).T

arr= interpolate.griddata(points, values, xi)
```

However, I had to do mine a little differently because my x and y were 2D arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

# Creating x and y of size=(m,m) from someArray of size(m,) 
# (x and y here are my version of OP's new_xx and new_yy)
x, y = np.meshgrid(someArray, someArray)

# These are my version of OP's x and y
xScaled = x * scaleFactor
yScaled = y * scaleFactor

points = np.array([xScaled.ravel(), yScaled.ravel()]).T
values = myMatrix.ravel()  # myMatrix has size=(m,m) and includes complex numbers, similar to OP's yy variable
xi = np.array([x.ravel(), y.ravel()]).T

# 2D interpolation
myInterp2d = interpolate.griddata(points, values, xi, method='linear')

# Returning my data to original shape
myNewMatrix = myInterp2d.reshape(myMatrix.shape)
```

Pay attention to your output though, because the griddata function doesn't seem to offer any options for extrapolation, it just fills with nans.